# How to get json data's and convert it to strings

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm new to websockets and json here in python. I just want to know how to convert json data's to strings just like this

```
{'data': {'id': 26, 'level': 2, 'message': 'Something was Detected'}}
```

into

```
"26"
"2"
"Something was Detected"
```

or any format just to make it as a string.

I'm receiving my json data from a local websocket heres the code.

```
async with websockets.connect(url) as websocket:
        data = dict(topic='device:10', event="phx_join", payload={}, ref=0)
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(data))

        # Json data will be receive here
        message = await websocket.recv()

        # then it will be printed here
        print(message)

        # I need to convert the message into string

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello('ws://localhost:4000/socket/websocket'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got my desired output

```
async with websockets.connect(url) as websocket:
    data = dict(topic='device:10', event="phx_join", payload={}, ref=0)
    await websocket.send(json.dumps(data))

    # Json data will be receive here
    message = await websocket.recv()

    # then it will be printed here
    print(message)

    # The answer for the question
    message_json = json.loads(message)
    id = message_json['data']['id']
    print(id)
    level = message_json['data']['level']
    print(level)
    mes = message_json['data']['message']
    print(mes)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello('ws://localhost:4000/socket/websocket')
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
data = json.loads(message)
list_of_strings = [str(v) for k, v in data['data'].items()]
```

Comment: I can't upvote because I'm new here but your answer help me a lot. I will post the workaround that I used to get my desired output

Comment: Okay, I'm glad I was able to help!